# How to load Customizable input fields from Zapier CLI

Tags: javascript, zapier, zapier-cli

I'm loading custom input fields for access and receive data from particular API which need user input data. After getting the response(responses are received by accessing input fields dropdown box), I need to show received response data on the same input fields stack where I had the first input field sets (by like re-rendering the input fields). Is it possible?

How to load data and store in the program without using drop down input fields?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following your question, you should be able to do that via a series of functions in the `inputData` array. Each should check that whatever pre-reqs it needs are set, and then return data. If it's still waiting on another field, it can return `[]` and have no affect on the input form. For example (very basic pseudocode):

```js
inputFields: [
  // field for key "color"
  (z, bundle)=>{
    if (bundle.inputData.color) {
      return [a, b, c] // where each of these is a valid field object
    } else { 
      return []
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The data i want to loaded were load from same input fields and from the loaded data i want to add some more input fields according to the data load from initial input fields.Will this step check for new inputs and rendered them to input fields automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'd have to try it out. If a function returns fields, i don't remember offhand under what conditions the function re-runs. should be easy enough to test out though!

Comment: Is it possible to have input fields in two time in zapier? I mean first  input set in one step and in another step can we have another input fields?

Comment: they can't be separated into two screens, no. it's a single set of inputs. you can re-render them all (since the functions may return different values), but it's just the one view